# Function template to turn a string literal into a std::array

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible to have a function template that'll take a `"string literal"` and  return a `std::array<char,N>` equivalent to

```
 char array[] = "string literal";
```

?

I'm wrapping POSIX APIs and I'd like to have a `mkstemp` function template that'll take a string literal and return

```
std::pair<
 ModifiedLiteral //template turned into actual name (probably in std::array)
,FileFd_RW       //My fd wrapper
>;
```

without using the heap.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::string`?

Comment: @BoPersson, performance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
#include <array>
#include <functional>
#include <cstddef>

template <std::size_t N> std::array<char, N> parse_literal(const char (&lit)[N]) {
  std::array<char, N> arr;
  std::copy(lit, lit + N, arr.begin());

  return arr;
}

void foo() {
  parse_literal("This is my rifle, this is my gun");
}
```

Comment: I would use a `std::size_t` instead of an `int` for the template parameter.

Comment: @NathanOliver, so would I. I am contemplating editing it  :) -- Done. However, the difference is purely academic. I can't really imagine a string literal over 4GB :)

Comment: @NathanOliver Why? Are there even any systems that support stack objects that big?

Comment: @PSkocik Mainly because `std::size_t` documents the intention, and it was designed especially for this reason, to use it as a size index. If you look at [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) you'll see that it uses a `size_t` as template parameter.

Comment: @PSkocik No but vsoftco explained why very nicely.

Comment: @SergeyA (pedantic) You can also use `std::begin(lit)`/`std::end(lit)` instead of passing the pointers around.

Comment: @vsoftco, I see no benefit in this whatsoever, rather than extra typing - which is not a benefit.

Comment: @SergeyA Sure, here it makes no difference. I use it in generic code, whenever your iterators are not necessarily random access, so the code looks exactly the same no matter if you pass arrays to it or say linked lists.

Comment: @vsoftco, in a different scenario I would use a different code. However, in this case extra typing can not be justified by the fact that it is justified in some other scenario, right?

Comment: @SergeyA It's just a matter of style, nothing wrong with your answer. I prefer to use iterators instead of pointer arithmetic, and also `std::next` instead of raw addition. The main reason is that if one decides later to change the signature of those functions, in that case one won't have to change the body. But again, I'm not advocating you do the same, I just mentioned that `std::begin` works on arrays also, as some people don't know this.

Comment: @vsoftco, it is a good  point about std::begin working on arrays.

Comment: @SergeyA You're copying the EOS, too. Is this right? I guess it should be `array< char, N - 1 > a;`

Answer (score 6):

If your compiler supports C++14 you could use `std::index_sequence` to craft a machinery that would copy the string literal in compile time:

```
template<std::size_t N, std::size_t... I>
constexpr 
std::array<char, N>
a2t_impl(char const (&str)[N], std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    return {str[I]...};
}

template<std::size_t N, typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
constexpr 
std::array<char, N>
a2t(char const (&str)[N]) {
    return a2t_impl(str, Indices());
}

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr 
std::array<char, N> 
stringtoarray(char const (&str)[N]) {
  return a2t(str);
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b12ab4a3cd48379)

Comment: And if it doesn't, it's not that hard to make one yourself.